# Updating In App Apple Subscription pricing smoothly

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription

I have published an iOS app version with Apple subscription with $6/month, now in next update I have to update pricing to $12/year.

When I use edit option on iTunesconnect it only allow to edit price i.e. from $6 to $12 but it doesn't allow to edit subscription period i.e. from month to year. Therefore I thought there is only one possibility that create new subscription and associate with app, but still what to do with old subscription like if I remove it from iTunes what will happen to existing users what next update is published?

Answer (score 1):

In our case we don't delete the old in app purchases so that users that already purchased them can keep using them.
In the next app release we make sure that the app display only the new in app purchases with the updated prices.
This way new prices effects only users that are trying to purchase now and have the most updated app version.